# How to import "PermissionStatus"?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

In my angular application I want to use the `PermissionStatus` of JavaScript. A reference can be found [at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PermissionStatus).

When I try to import it in one of my angular `.ts` files, my IDE (IntelliJ) cannot find the class.

```
navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation' }).then(function (permissionStatus: PermissionStatus) {
  console.log('geolocation permission status is ', permissionStatus.state);
});
```

<kbd>[CODE EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gf9jd4-stackoverflow-fgzkwj)</kbd>

It complains:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PermissionStatus'.
```

Even using `navigator.permissions` gives me an error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'permissions' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
```

How can I import `PermissionStatus`?

Answer (score 1):

`PermissionStatus` types have been added in typescript version `3.5`, so if it is possible for you to update the package, installing additional types is not necessary

Comment: Just in case, at this moment angular _8.0_ _doesn't_ support typescript _3.5_, you will see compiler's error, but very soon this will be changed and I think this answer will be more relevant for people who will find it later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$ npm install --save-dev @types/navigator-permissions
```

for more detail, you can check [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24923) as well -